# What tense is "has became"?

Tags: tense

What tense is "has became" in the sentence below

> "Drug policy reform **has** also **became** a topic of international debate"?

I know the verb **"become"** and came across **"has *become"*** but haven't seen **"has became"** in a sentence before.

Comment: It's wrong. It should be the present perfect tense: auxiliary verb "has" + past participle "become". Where did you find that sentence?

Comment: It might be duplicate  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93756/became-vs-has-become

Answer (score 3):

This is a present perfect tense but in wrong construction. The present perfect construction is `Has/have+past particple`

I made this mistake once, when I was twelve. It's because typical verbs have same past and past participle forms. But, *become* is an irregular verb, *became* is past tense and *become* is past participle.

We have a good source about perfect tense. You might want to read it [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Answer (score 2):

become -> became -> become

"to become" is irregular and the author used it wrong. He had to use "become" because it is the third form (past participle) which is needed.

Present Perfect (active): have/has + past participle

Answer (score 1):

The author should have written:  It became or has become, if no one else talks about it then they could write had become.  If discussions were still underway then maybe used as a participle in itself, "Having become a topic discussion.."

Answer (score -1):

Wrong, because it's related to the present, it's not at some remote past time. What they really want to say is:

Drug policy reform has also recently /lately become a topic of international debate